# How to call a function inside .FLA from an AS Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, air, program-entry-point

My Main class is added to the stage of my .fla and I want to remove and re-add/"restart" the class when it finishes animating. All of my animations are happening in Main and are added to the display tree inside Main. How can I run the `finishNow()` function from within Main.as?

The .fla file:

```
var run:Main = new Main(this);
stage.addChild(run);

function finishNow() {
    stage.removeChild(run);
    var run:Main = new Main(this);
    stage.addChild(run);
}
```

The Main.as file:

```
var stageHolder:Object;

public function Main(stageHolderTemp) {
        stageHolder = stageHolderTemp; 
        trace(stageHolder);
}

function callFinishFunction():void {
    // how to call finishNow() function from .fla file here
}
```

EDIT: The design of the program has changed. Still trying to do the same thing (call finishNow() function – but it is now in Program.as). It all works fine, except throws an error for `program.finishNow();`:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

The .fla file:

It now does not contain any code. It is linked to Program.as.

The Program.as file:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Program extends MovieClip {


        public function Program() {

            startNow();
        }

        function startNow() {
            var run:Main = new Main(this);
            addChild(run);
        }

        function finishNow() {
            removeChild(run);
            var run:Main = new Main(this);
            addChild(run);
        }

    }

}
```

The Main.as file:

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        var stageHolder:Object;
        public var program:Program;

        public function Main(stageHolderTemp) {
            stageHolder = stageHolderTemp; 
            trace(stageHolder);

            someFunctionsThatDrawGraphics();
        }

        function callFinishFunction():void {
            // how to call finishNow() function from Program.as file here?
            program.finishNow();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your .fla linked to Main.as file, you can directly called. try this:

```
public function Main() {
        finishNow();
}
```

[image]

.fla code

```
function testFunction()
{
    trace("111");
}
```

.as file

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class Main extends MovieClip {


        public function Main() {

            testFunction();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When I try to call `finishNow();`/`testFunction();` it comes up with the error 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addFrameScript. My Main AS Class already extends Sprite so it can't extend MovieClip (does it have to in order to call the function?)

Comment: you must knowing different Sprite vs MovieClip. sprite not have a framescript. Unlike the Sprite object, a MovieClip object has a timeline. so, if you want to called function in .fla must extend MovieClip.

Comment: Okay, I've changed Sprite to MovieClip, but it gives an ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Main(). Expected 1, got 0. The animations that drew in Main don't appear anymore.

Comment: your Main Constructor must not have a any parameters. like `Main();` see a my code. and compare actual your code. my code right. If you still not working, copy & paste.

Comment: I copy & pasted and it works fine on its own without any other code. But it doesn't work in conjunction with the current `... stage.addChild(run); ...` code that is also in .fla file seen in my question post above. It throws an Error 1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 0.

Comment: Your design is wrong. Main.as. already refer the stage. Main.as is see a stage. and you syntax error `new Main(this);` Class Constructor not have any parameters. but you pass to `this`;

Comment: I don't understand how it compiled before if it was wrong. How can I fix this design of this?

Comment: shortly, `Main.as` position is same Timeline. `Main.as` just see a .fla stage. Think Timeline coding transplant `Main.as`. easily, `Main.as` is Empty MovieClip that already put stage.

Comment: I have updated the design a bit and can be seen in my updated question post. I hope this is similar to what you meant being wrong with it before. It now throws a TypeError? The whole program now works except this.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `addframeScript` to call FLA function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually , no need to create the class object every time . It will be enough to call a function in that class every time .

But for your question ..
Try this ....

[image: your Document Class]

In program.as

```
    var run:Main = new Main(this);
    run.addEventListener("FINISH",finishNow);
    addChild(run);
    function finishNow(e:Event)
    {
     }
```

In main.as ,

```
function callFinishFunction():void
 {
  dispatchEvent(new Event("FINISH"));
 }
```